# How to debug a SceneKit crash

Tags: scenekit

I need some help figuring out how to go about debugging this SceneKit crash.  It seems to happen randomly, and particularly more so on devices than in a simulator.  It happens on both iOS and OS X. I have no idea where to begin.

[image]

EDIT:
OK I think I may have found the problem - a background thread somehow causing a problem when setting a boolean value.  Seems to have gone away now by wrapping the call in `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{})`.

Comment: is that SpriteKit? A SpriteKit overlay in SceneKit?

Comment: @mnuages yes that's correct.